# Zeppelin: Jobs are not loading, its showing as Running

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Zeppelin:
Once I submit Spark Job over Zeppelin, the running job
or the finished job is not listed in JobManager.
Its stuck in loading state.

Answer (score 3):

This is to improve performance, loading jobs are disabled. You can enable as follows:
set`zeppelin.jobmanager.enable` to true in zeppelin-site.xml

Refer: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-4702